# Code to convert a .docx to an ooxml document package

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, docx

I was able to get the MainDocumentPart of a docx file using OpenXML, however wasn't able to get an ooxml document package like followings. Can anybody share some light on this?

```
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
        <Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2011/relationships/webextensiontaskpanes" Target="word/webextensions/taskpanes.xml"/>
        <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml"/>
      </Relationships>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is "Flat OPC" XML.

You can use [Eric White's approach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/29/transforming-flat-opc-format-to-open-xml-documents.aspx).

Or you can use docx4j.NET.  For that, first convert it to a docx4j WordprocessingMLPackage.  If you are starting with a C# string:

```
    private WordprocessingMLPackage getPkgFromString(string wordOpenXML)
    {

        // The string is UTF-16; convert it to UTF-8
        byte[] utf16Bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(wordOpenXML);
        byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, utf16Bytes);

        return  WordprocessingMLPackageFactory.createWordprocessingMLPackage(utf8Bytes);
    }
```

Then to get a C# WordprocessingDocument, use [WordprocessingDocumentFactory.cs](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j.NET/blob/master/docx4j.NET/src/main/c_sharp/Plutext/Docx4NET/WordprocessingDocumentFactory.cs)

Comment: Thanks a bunch!!! Actually I am interesting in transforming from an Open XML Documents to Flat OPC Format. I was able to find the solution from the link you provided and the link is here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/29/transforming-open-xml-documents-to-flat-opc-format.aspx You helped.